# PHP - Native Constant for HTTP GET|PUT|POST

Tags: php, http-post, httprequest, constants, http-get

Are there any constants for "GET", "POST", etc. defined inside of the native php language, I have already tried:

```
HTTP_METH_GET
```

etc.
but without success

Comment: `HTTP_METH_GET` is part of the `http` PECL package.

Comment: I just want something like const HTTP_GET = "get", if this exists in php

Comment: `define('HTTP_GET', 'get')` then. I don't believe it exists in the main PHP language, but that's what `define()` is for.

Comment: yes I know, thx.... I just wanted to know if something like this already exists before I define it myself

Comment: To see all the available constants you can use something like `print_r(get_defined_constants());`. As you can see, theres nothing available out of the box. As @Nickolaus suggested, defined your  own if you really want them.

Comment: thx for the hint,... the only available options are CURLOPT_HTTPGET etc. therefore I think self defined constants should be preferred since it is not reliable that curl is available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been a while since this was asked, but like mentioned in the comments there are no native constant predefined for GET HTTP Method GET.

This question should be set to 'answered'